# Play2.1 (Scala) leaking memory in Server Sent Event (Enumerator)

Tags: scala, playframework, server-sent-events

I'm working on an application where I want the server to send events to my JS front-end to show money transactions as they are processed.
The way I implemented works as intended; however, after a couple of hours I notice the heap increasing and consequently killing our server.
I read somewhere that it could be caused by nginx not being configured correctly, but the keep-alive is set to just a few seconds. I also saw a couple of posts regarding memory leak issues when one attempts something like the following:

```
  val newTransaction: Enumerator[String] = {
    Enumerator.generateM[String] {
      Promise.timeout(getNewTransactions, checkingInterval 500)
    }
  }
  ...

  Ok.stream(newTransaction &> EventSource()).as("text/event-stream")
```

getNewTransactions is just a method that hits Redis to check if any new transaction arrived for an account.

I tried updating my project to use the newest Scala version 2.10.2, but it seems that it doesn't solve it. In the meantime, I am resorting to JavaScript polling until I can figure it out. Does anyone have any idea how I might solve this?

Comment: At some point I profiled a similar action, and while enumerators eat up a lot of memory, they seem to free it at some point. Have you tried to profile your app locally?